# Connect Report Designer with BI CE Server 6.0

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-ctools

I have installed a BI server community edition and create a DataSource. This DataSource connect with a PostgreSQL database in another server (JDBC). Now, I have the Report Designer and I want to use the DataSource created in BI CE Server.

I can connect with PostgreSQL database from Report Designer creating a JDBC Datasource, but I want to connect with the DataSource created in BI Server.

How could i do that?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that creating a JNDI connection in Pentaho BI Server and Pentaho Report Designer (PRD). I leave this links of my blog where I have instructions of how to do it:

- [Configure JNDI Connection Pentaho BI Server](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fingmmurillo-dwh-bi.blogspot.com%2F2015%2F02%2Fconfiguracion-de-conexion-jndi-en.html)
- [Configure JNDI Connection Pentaho Report Designer](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fingmmurillo-dwh-bi.blogspot.com%2F2015%2F02%2Fcomo-configurar-una-conexion-jndi-en_18.html&edit-text=)

Also, when you create a report using PRD you have to Publish it to Pentaho BI Server. I hope it helps you.